# How to find all symlinks to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, find, symlink

This is my hierarchy:

```
aaaaaaaa
|_q
  |_a.txt
|_w
  |_l1
  |_l2
```

`l1` and `l2` are symlinks to `a.txt`.
I run this code to find all symlinks to `a.txt` in the `/aaaaaaaa`:

```
find ~/aaaaaaaa/ -exec ls -a {} ';' | grep '/home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt'
```

And it obviously doesn't work, cause I must compare realpath of file with path of `a.txt`. In what way I should do this?

Comment: Not possible.  The could be symlinks in unmounted filesystems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have GNU/BSD find just use `-samefile` primary.

```
$ find -L ~/aaaaaaaa/ -samefile ~/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt 
/home/oguz/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt
/home/oguz/aaaaaaaa/w/l2
/home/oguz/aaaaaaaa/w/l1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
referenceid=$(stat -Lc '%d-%i' /home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt)
find ~/aaaaaaaa/ -type l -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
do
  if [ "$(stat -Lc '%d-%i' "$filename")" = "$referenceid" ]
  then
    printf -- '%s\n' "$filename"
  fi
done
```

This initially gets a unique ID for a base file, e.g. `/home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt`. The ID is computed from the device ID and the inode, using `stat`.

Then it parses your folder using `file`, limited to symbolic links (thanks to `-type l`), and for each filename it gets the device ID and inode using `stat` again, using its `-L` option that dereferences the link before fetching the ID.

For each device ID and inode that matches the reference ID, it prints the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` with `-type l` to search for symbolic links:

```
find aaaaaaaa -type l -exec sh -c '
  for i; do
    printf "%s -> %s\n" "$i" "$(readlink -f "$i")"
  done
' sh {} +
```

The shell script prints link path and canonical path of the symlink using `readlink -f` (but you could also use `realpath` instead):

Example output:

```
aaaaaaaa/w/l1 -> /home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt
aaaaaaaa/w/l2 -> /home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt
```

Use `grep` to filter the result using the absolute path, e.g.

```
find aaaaaaaa -type l -exec sh -c '
  for i; do
    printf "%s -> %s\n" "$i" "$(readlink -f "$i")"
  done
' sh {} + | grep '/home/khodor/aaaaaaaa/q/a.txt$'
```

Note the `$` at the end of the pattern to match the end of the line.